# toggleClass not removing initial div img source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to toggle between images, but the code I have is just laying one on top of the other, not removing the initial image. This is what I have:

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('box'),
    text = document.getElementById('menu');
button.onclick = function () {
    var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
    text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
};
$("#box").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
</script>
```

I have the intial image set up as a div and the second one as a class:

```
.close {
    width: 29px;    
    z-index: 1;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: crosshair;
   background-image: url('http://gabrielamagana.com/project1/ndxz-studio/site/sample/close-eye.png');
}
```

This is probably not the best way to set this up but '=I'm fairly new at this.

Comment: nowhere you are changing the image source and also make sure that the scripts are executed in an dom ready handler

Comment: Your script can be shorten as `<script>jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#box").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("red");
    });
})</script>`

Comment: Hi this is my first time using this site. Sorry I dont really know how to use it yet. 

My HTML is just a div with and image. How can I toggle between Image Sources instead of classes?

Comment: you want to change the image `http://gabrielamagana.com/project1/ndxz-studio/site/sample/close-eye.png` to another one?

Comment: Still it will be easier for us if you can share the html... which element has the class `box`

Comment: It worked with one of the answers! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to toggle images, try the following technique:

*I don't have a clear understanding of your existing HTML structure so this simply serves as an example.*

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32T3p/1/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class='img1' id='dvImage'>&nbsp;</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var ele = $('#dvImage');
    ele.click(function(){
        ele.toggleClass("img2");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.img1, .img2{
    width:400px;    
    height:100px; 
}

.img1{
    background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff');
}

.img2{
    background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/aaa'); 
}
```

*NOTE: To get rid of the flicker between initial image loads, use a "[sprite image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)." You'll gain performance by reducing requests and eliminate the flicker associated with loading new images.*

Comment: One `toggleClass("img2")` is enough.  The later CSS will override the default image.